# Is there any way to get rid of error "deprecated conversion from string" in this graphic program?

Tags: c++, string, bgi

```
#include <graphics.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int gd = DETECT,gm;

    /* warning deprecated convesion from string to char* [wWrite-strings] */
    initgraph(&gd,&gm, "C:\\TURBOC3\\BGI");         

    circle(300,300,50);
    closegraph();
    getch();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you say "sublime graphic program" do you mean the [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com) text-editor?

Comment: Besides that, please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: yes,sublime text editor .

Comment: if you have solution ,then please try to solve my case as well sir

Comment: BGI graphics is almost as old as the arc, as are most compilers that support it - you would be better updating to something more recent than 2000. In any event, documentation for `initgraph()` says the third argument is of type `char *` (implying to more modern compilers that the passed string may be changed). A string literal cannot be changed (at least, not without undefined behaviour). Create a separate array of `char` (of suitable sized), copy the string literal to it, and then pass that array to the function. Also backslashes in string literals need to be escaped with a second backslash.

Answer (score 1):

Store the string in a modifiable array:

```
char bgi[] = "C:\\TURBOC3\\BGI";
initgraph(&gd,&gm,bgi);
```